# XML format in SQL Server BCP

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms, bcp

I run below statement to generate a XML output in SQL Server:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * FROM DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity  FOR XML AUTO" 
     queryout "C:\Sample\Test.xml" -T  -c -r -C 65001  -t, '
```

The output is:

```
<DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity Id="1" PortalUserId="11"/><DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity Id="2" PortalUserId="22"/>
```

But I want the result be like this:

```
<DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity Id="1" PortalUserId="11"/>
<DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity Id="2" PortalUserId="22"/>
```

Would you please answer how can I get the correct result?

Comment: Like HTML, XML derives from SGML and doesn't care about whitespace between elements. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thank You. first format, when the table has many rows, is not easy readable by eye.
I want the element "DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity" be located under each other.

Comment: You can use an editor which can pretty print your xml for you. Or build string manually by casting xml to nvarchar and then adding some newlines.

Comment: Does this answer give you a direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019414/3710053

Comment: Thank you, But I want do that in a query.

Comment: select replace((select * from yourtable  FOR XML AUTO), '><','>
<')

Comment: there should be a new line between the > < but comments don't accept that :)

Comment: @siggemannen
It just paste a space not a break line.

Comment: That's what i wrote, change the space to a newline

Comment: `CHAR(10)` for those playing along at home.

Comment: But how and where should I use char(10)?
@AlwaysLearning

Comment: select replace((select * from yourtable FOR XML AUTO), '><','>' + CHAR(10) + '<')

Comment: or if you sit on windows: select replace((select * from yourtable FOR XML AUTO), '><','>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '<')

Comment: Thank You Bro! but a bit change should be applied.
I post the answer and mention you.
@siggemannen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen

Split element by replace in query level and use "-r \n":

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select replace((select * FROM DataCenter.Dbo.TblCity  FOR XML AUTO), '/><','/>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '<')" queryout "C:\Sample\Test.xml" -T  -c -r \n -C 65001 '
```